# Children interfering with hitTestObject (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in as3 using FlashDevelop.

I have a button class that gets clicked when the player collides with it. No problem. Hit detection is working, clicking is working, that's not an issue. This specific extension of my button class has a label (specifically, a `TextField`) above it, containing a short String.

The problem is that when I add the label as a child, it changes the `hitArea` of the button. The `TextField` has a larger `hitArea`, and I think it is overriding the `hitArea` of just the button itself.

Solutions that I'm looking for (any, not necessarily all):

1. A way to tell `hitTestObject` to ignore the `hitArea` of the button's children
2. A type of label for which this wouldn't be a problem
3. A way to re-override the `hitArea` of the button*.

I've been programming for about two years now, so I can understand advice pretty well, but I've only been teaching myself as3 for a little under a month.

*I know that in some flash IDEs, it's stupidly easy to change the `hitArea`, since there is usually an easy window in which to do it. FlashDevelop is more code-focused, meaning that all the `MovieClip()` and `Frame` shenanigans have been abstracted away. The only way that I've seen to change the `hitArea` through code is to assign it to a `Sprite`, but that doesn't make sense to me, especially in this situation, because the button, at its base, extends `Sprite`

Thanks in advance, everyone.

A quick screenshot I threw together. Thankfully, I can just `TextField.border = true;` and show the exact `hitArea`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW6ff.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create an transparent (0% alpha) sprite inside of the upgrade that is the specific dimensions for hit tests. Then from there, you hit test against this object instead of the parent like so. `if(player.hitTestObject(upgrade.hitBox)) {`

Comment: I'm actually doing the opposite and having the buttons looking for the player. i.e. `if(Button.hitTestObject(Player))`

Could the problem be that I'm using the button object for the check? I'm gonna try comparing against the button's skin, instead of the object itself. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It worked! It's now checking against the image, not the object, and it works perfectly. Thank you!

It now does `if(Button.skin.hitTestObject(Player))`